# Calibre fails to work with system tray in Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, notification-area, calibre

To start Calibre in the system tray, normally you can execute the command:

```
calibre --start-in-tray
```

When I do it, it always fails and opens in a normal window. Executing the above instruction in the terminal tells me:

```
Failed to create system tray icon, your desktop environment probably does not support the StatusNotifier spec
```

It would surprise me if this was really true, since I have other tray icons working like Teamviewer, Fl.ux, and Syncthing-GTK working in the tray.

I tried installing KDE and booting into it, and the problem was solved, but I don't plan on continuing to use KDE and Cinnamon side-by-side on the same OS install. Also, in my troubleshooting, I learned the devs recommend uninstalling the version of Calibre that is in the OS repositories and instead install the binary with a wget command from the [Calibre website](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux).

Is the calibre system tray icon really incompatible with the Cinnamon tray? If so, is there another tray I could install?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this on a forum where the creator of Calibre, Kovid Goyal, frequents and he issued the following answer:

> Yes, it really is. You need a tray that implements the StatusNotifier
>   spec. calibre does not support the obsolete X window based status
>   icons as they have many issues.